# How can i redirect to another page after the alert is display in XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How can I redirect to another page after the alert is displayed and the user clicked on ok?

Below is the code I used

```js
var Admin =  doc.getItemValueString("Admin");
var scriptCode = "alert('Email send to the admin: " + Admin + "')";
view.postScript(scriptCode);
```

When I try to use "context.redirectToHome()" then the alert did not work again. Any idea how I can go about these or any other messagebox function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the redirection to your client side `scriptCode` with `window.location=URL`:

```js
var scriptCode = "alert('Email send to the admin: " + Admin + "'); window.location = 'http://www.yourNewPage.com'";
```

You can calculate the target URL in your code before and add it as a variable (like you do with "Admin").